# HTML tag <sup> text is not going out when I submit and redirecting to other page means superscription still showing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to show date like 23<sup>rd</sup>  or 4<sup>th</sup> in web page. like

Today Date :  20<sup>th</sup> Dec

there is one submit button.When I submit this and it redirect to another page.when I submit it do query on backend, so it take time and one image come which show redirecting to another page. but at the time of redirecting this  <sup>th</sup> still appears until when whole data loads. So I want that at time of redirecting this <sup>th</sup> not should be there.

```
<td class="inputLabels">Pickup On</td>
<td style="padding-left:25px;width:200px">

<span class='fields'>

<?php
if(is_object($this->service->pickupDate)){
   echo $this->service->pickupDate->format('d').'<sup>',
   $this->service->pickupDate->format('S') ,'</sup>'.
   $this->service->pickupDate->format("M 'y").' '.
   $this->service->pickupDate->format("h:i A");
                            }
```

Comment: @HarryDenley , I have pasted my code.It is giving correct output on web. But when submitting that page and redirecting other that th or rd still showing

Comment: I can't make sense of your question - may you rephrase @Bharat, okease?

Comment: @HarryDenley , I have edited my question. Check now it is clear or not. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the <sup>th</sup>, you could wrap it in a container, and use jQuery to dynamically remove it. For example;

`<sup id="th">',
   $this->service->pickupDate->format('S') ,'</sup>'.`

and the Jquery (put a condition to notify jQuery when the redirect has been triggered)

`$('#th').hide();`

I hope that's what you're after.
Here's [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QtmZx/)

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what you want, you only provided parts of your code which I don't fully understand, but I'll have a stab at it none the less.

In general, if there are elements showing up on a page that you don't want to you could delete them using jQuery.

You can either:

Delete *all* sup elements:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('sup').remove();
});
```

**Or**

give the sup element an id

```
<sup id="supId"></sup>
```

and only delete that specific element by id

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#supId').remove();
});
```